# WAS RSA selectively deploy module

Tags: websphere, rsa

In a WAS, using RSA for development, if the .ear has several modules, is there a way to deploy only a single module?
This becomes necessary because if I make a small change to a small module, I do not need to redeploy the entire ear.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is why "partial upgrade" parts of the interface exist. They are usable if you can provide single files or zip containing the changes. If you have however edited deployment descriptor or other meta files you must re-deploy the whole application.